# Not able to Boot Ubuntu after BIOS update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 14.10

Device name: HP Pavilion 15-n205tx Notebook PC

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 and everything was OK but after I have updated my BIOS, it gave me an error that file is missing or corrupted.. and it gave me two option below `Enter=OS Selection` and `ESC=UEFI Firmware Setting`.

However when I select Boot Device Option there are four options:

- OS Boot Manager
- Ubuntu(Hard disk name)
- Ubuntu (hard disk name)
- Boot EFI File

I select 2nd or 3rd Option for booting into ubuntu OS.. However I Want a Proper Boot screen.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Did you only upgrade your BIOS or also the UEFI system?  If the latter, you should reconfigure the UEFI system to have whatever you need/want.

Comment: Thanks - Fabby, I have resonfigure the UEFI Setting.. Its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a UEFI system, the firmware does not get loaded from ROM any more: if gets loaded from disk (into RAM)

So if you want do re-define your UEFI menu:

1. **[Make a system back-up first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)** (You're definitely user type 4)
2. Go into the UEFI menu settings and upgrade the UEFI firmware
3. Then delete the menu items you don't need any more.

If anything goes wrong in 2. and/or 3.: restore the system back-up!

Comment: Thank Flabby, Can you also guide how to enable wifi, it RALINK CORP 3290 Wireless drivers

Comment: That one would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)  (I'm sorry, but I have Intel and BroadCom, so I know nothing of RALink)